# Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders

Tags: elasticsearch

```
mai 01 23:27:15 Akira elasticsearch[26881]:         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92)
mai 01 23:27:15 Akira elasticsearch[26881]:         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:85)
mai 01 23:27:15 Akira elasticsearch[26881]: 2018-05-01 23:27:15,572 main ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders.
mai 01 23:27:15 Akira elasticsearch[26881]: 2018-05-01 23:27:15,573 main ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders.
mai 01 23:27:15 Akira elasticsearch[26881]: 2018-05-01 23:27:15,574 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "rolling" for logger config "root"
mai 01 23:27:15 Akira elasticsearch[26881]: 2018-05-01 23:27:15,574 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "index_indexing_slowlog_rolling" for logger config "index.indexing.slowlog.i
mai 01 23:27:15 Akira elasticsearch[26881]: 2018-05-01 23:27:15,575 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "index_search_slowlog_rolling" for logger config "index.search.slowlog"
mai 01 23:27:15 Akira elasticsearch[26881]: 2018-05-01 23:27:15,575 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "deprecation_rolling" for logger config "org.elasticsearch.deprecation"
mai 01 23:27:15 Akira systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
mai 01 23:27:15 Akira systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

How can I fix it, I was try to start Elastic Search and I receive this message. I'm in Ubuntu Budgie 18.04, Elastic Search 1.51, installed by a `.deb`, and Java 1.8.0. I researched : [Log errors when starting Es](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/log4j-errors-when-starting-es/64484), [Es doesn’t start and there is no log](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-doesnt-start-and-there-is-no-log/88055) ... but nothing worked.

Comment: Please add more information..

Comment: Well, when I try to run it manually `/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch` I receive this [log](https://ghostbin.com/paste/eexho)

Comment: [This](https://ghostbin.com/paste/euqep) is my `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` file

Comment: [This](https://ghostbin.com/paste/dy5x6) one is my `/var/log/elasticsearch/Elastic\ Search\ Server.log` file of log.

Comment: Did you found some answer for this question ?

Comment: `sudo service elasticsearch stop` and `sudo chmod +x /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch` ( run `sudo service elasticsearch status` twice times, if it is active it worked )

Answer (score 4):

You must set Log Path and Data path.
İt's in the "/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml"

path.data:
path.logs:

Comment: This is the right answer. I my case, those settings were not in the /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml file (CentOS 8), and that was causing it not to start.

Comment: Default value on Debian Buster is "path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch" and "path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch"